# Don't wake screen on notifications when locked

Tags: lock-screen, notification

When I lock my laptop, if chrome or other apps have a notification it will wake the screen. How can I disable that while still keeping it locked and open?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you use Ubuntu 18.04 and up, or variant of Ubuntu with the GNOME 3 desktop, you can search for `Settings -> Notifications` and turn off `Lock Screen Notifications`.

[image]

**Note:** This will disable lock screen notifications entirely. Currently there is no way to prevent waking the locked device without disabling them.

Like and follow the [gnome-settings #30 feature request](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon/-/issues/30), which adds an option to avoid waking the lock screen on notifications.

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem. There should be a way to have lock screen notifications without waking the screen (like on Android - iOS is very bad in this aspect - Gnome Shell seems to have copied their bad design).

Comment: I want it to make the notification sound but not light up all my monitors just because of some notification. This solution will completely disable notifications when locked.

Comment: There is a discussion at GNOME gitlab: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon/-/issues/30 (Option to disable screen wake for lock screen notifications)