# How can I stop notifications from keeping my monitor awake?

Tags: gnome, power-management, monitor

Running Ubuntu 22.04 (Wayland + Gnome), it seems that notifications (e.g., Thunderbird indicating new mail, or snapd informing me I need to exit an app so it can update) will wake up the sleeping monitor and prevent it from going back to sleep (DPMS) until the notification is dismissed.

I do not want notifications to wake my screen, and I certainly don't want power saving to be inhibited if a notification is onscreen.

(Notifications will become 'inactive'--no longer displayed on screen, only in the notification history--if there's keyboard or mouse activity, such as during normal use, but they apparently don't make that transition if the computer is sitting idle.)

How can I fix this?

Alternatively is there an existing bug report for this that I can follow, and if not, what package am I even supposed to report this bug against, and what other information can I gather to help diagnose / resolve the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Don't wake screen on notifications when locked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1151783/dont-wake-screen-on-notifications-when-locked)

Comment: @Cas: After about a week of testing, it does appear your linked workaround (disable notifications on the lock screen) seems to mitigate the issue (despite the fact that my my PC isn't set to lock automatically, and I don't lock it manually). Thanks!